# Matlab out of memory error behave differently in one and two dimensional arrays

Tags: matlab

Today I have the need to allocate a vector with size 100000 in Matlab. I try to do it simply using:

```
a=ones(100000);
```

which my Matlab angrily answered with:

```
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

Which is strange since I have Matlab 64 bit running on a 64 bit machine with 8 GB RAM. I tried many of the "resolving out of memory errors in Matlab" recipe in SO or other places but no luck so far.

Now I'm more confused when something like:

```
a=ones(10000,10000);
```

Runs without problem in my machine.

Does this mean that Matlab have some mechanism to limit the number of elements of a vector in a single-dimensional space?

Comment: `a=ones(100000);` is equivalent to `a=ones(100000,100000);`

Comment: That seems right! Any ideas so a=ones(100000); can be created within the memory limit?

Comment: See if [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91711-what-is-the-maximum-matrix-size-for-each-platform) helps.

Comment: Turns out I've the wrong concept about matlab syntax in the first place. Thanks for your help, Divakar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Today I have the need to allocate a vector with size 100000 in Matlab.

Now, as noted in the comments and such, the method you tried (`a=ones(100000);`) creates a 100000x100000 matrix, which is not what you want.

I would suggest you try:

```
a = ones(1, 100000);
```

Since that creates a vector rather than a matrix.

Comment: Thanks. My confusion stems from my assumption that ones(100000) is ones(100000,1). 

Matlab newbie here.

Comment: No worries, Matlab has lots of little gotcha's like that.

Answer (score 3):

## Arguments Matter

Calling Matlab's `ones()` or `zeros()` or `magic()` with a single argument `n`, creates a *square* matrix with size `n-by-n`:

```matlab
>> a = ones(5)
  a = 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1
```

Calling the same functions with 2 arguments `(r, c)` instead creates a matrix of size `r-by-c`:

```matlab
>> a = ones(2, 5)
  a = 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1
```

This is all well documented in [Matlab's documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html).

## Size Matters Too

### Doubles

Having said this, when you do `a = zeros(1e6)` you are creating a square matrix of size `1e6 * 1e6 = 1e12`. Since these are doubles the total allocated size would be `8 * 1e12 Bytes` which is circa `(8 * 1e12) / 1024^3 = 7450.6GB`. Do you have this much RAM on your machine?

Compare this with `a = zeros(1, 1e6)` which creates a column-vector of size `1 * 1e6 = 1e6`, for a total allocated size of `(8 * 1e6) / 1024^3 = 7.63MB`.

### Logicals

Logical values, on the other hand are boolean values, which can be set to either `0` or `1` representing `False` or `True`. With this in mind, you can allocate matrices of logicals using either [`false()`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/false.html) or [`true()`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/true.html). Here the same single-argument rule applies, hence `a = false(1e6)` creates a square matrix of size `1e6 * 1e6 = 1e12`. Matlab today, as many other programming languages, stores bit values, such as booleans, into single Bytes. Even though there is a clear cost in terms of memory usage, such a mechanism provides significant performance improvements. This is because it is [accessing single bits is a slow operation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/22439-logical-array-memory-allocation).

The total allocated size of our `a = false(1e6)` matrix would therefore be `1e12 Bytes` which is circa `1e12 / 1024^3 = 931.32GB`.

Comment: Maybe you can look into if using `logicals` gives us the luxury of having more elements? Though not part of the question, but could be  just bonus stuff for OP.

Comment: @Divakar You mean explain that logicals are booleans and therefore occupy less memory than doubles?

Comment: Yeah! Could be interesting to see.

Comment: And on the editing part, if you want to have little smaller fontsize for the section titles, you can use `##` instead of `#` when starting a section title text. Just in case, if you would like your posts that way.

Comment: @Divakar Ok makes sense I added a part about logicals.

Comment: Awesome, looks good! Thank you for taking the request and going that extra mile!

Comment: Actually that was my pleasure. I even learned something while doing so. :D

Comment: That's the best thing about Stackoverflow! Questions that poke you to look for more new info, answers from others that inspire you to write efficient codes and finally the comments! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well the first declaration tries to build a matrix of 1000000x1000000 ones. That would be **~931 GB**.

The second tries to declare a matrix of 10000 x 10000. That would be **~95MB**.

I assumed each one is stored on a byte. If they use floats, than the requested memory size will be 4 times larger.

Comment: Add a link and a quote to Matlab's documentation and this answer is complete.

Comment: To complete this: For making the one dimensional vector of size 100000, this can be used: `ones(100000,1)`

Comment: @JoErNanO well, I stated that in my answer :). Anyway the problem was the memory footprint of the matrix. I couldn't check it cos i don't have Matlab with me.